# how to create dynamic fields using sequalize library

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need help creating and initializing dynamic fields in my application. Specifically, I have retrieved field data from MySQL and structured it, but I am not sure how to use hooks to initialize the fields. Can someone provide advice on how to accomplish this task effectively?

This is my sequalize data model.

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const getColumns = async (tableName) => {
        console.log(tableName);
        const tableColumns = `SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS columnName
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'results';`;
        const data = await sequelize.query(tableColumns);
        return data[0].reduce(
            (acc, cur) => {
                if (cur.columnName !== 'id') {
                    acc[cur.columnName] = {
                        type: DataTypes.STRING,
                        allowNull: true,
                    };
                    return acc;
                }
                return acc;
            },
            {
                roll: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    allowNull: false,
                },
            },
        );
    };

    sequelize.addHook('beforeCreate', async (attributes, options) => {
        if (options.tableName === 'results') {
            const columns = await getColumns(options.tableName);
            Object.assign(attributes, columns);
        }
    });

    class Result extends Model {}

    Result.init(
        {},
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'results',
            tableName: 'results',
            underscored: true,
        },
    );

    return Result;
};
```

This is how I configured sequalize.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-dynamic-require
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../config/database.js`)[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter((file) => {
        return file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js';
    })
    .forEach((file) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line global-require,import/no-dynamic-require
        const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to turn the model registration function into `async` and use it in a model's `init` (there is no need to use hooks - they are for data manipulation and not for model registration):

```js
module.exports = async (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const getColumns = async (tableName) => {
...
class Result extends Model {}
    Result.init(
        await getColumns(sequelize, 'results'),
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'results',
            tableName: 'results',
            underscored: true,
        },
    );

    return Result;
```

But that way you can't define class fields dynamically to have a ready-to-instantiate model class with all needed fields from a table.

Comment: await will not work inside the Result.init because async is not defined, so I did it this way
```
getColumns('results').then((columns) => {
            return columns;
        }
```
But still not working, it is trying to create data on these fields ```INSERT INTO `results` (`id`,`created_at`,`updated_at``)``` there should be more fields.

Comment: The reason is to do this way because my table is dynamic and the admin can create fields from the client, that's why I tried this way.

Comment: Ok, I added `async` for the whole function and you will need to call with await now in the registration models code

Comment: I appreciate your help, for using async my model is showing undefined when I try to call the model.

Comment: Did you add `await` on the model registration call?